# Show "sub-submodules" in OmNet++ Tkentv

Tags: omnet++

I have a huge hierarchal topology which turns to be quite large if I write in just one module. So I created one module for each level of hierarchy. This module has lower levels as its submodules, which in turn would have its lower levels as its submodules. This however means that during simulation, only the highest level of the hierarchy would be shown in the Tkenv graphical window.

**Can I control how many levels of submodules should be shown in the simulation window?**

If this cannot be done, I'd have to resort to one huge file. **Any alternatives would help too!**

Comment: If I remember right, you can double click on one module in the GUI to see the submodules. But I think, this is not what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in OMNeT++, although you can certainly extend the graphical frontend (either TkEnv or QtEnv) to allow that. In the meantime, you might have some success by opening individual hierarchy levels in separate windows (possibly by autogenerating a `.tkenv` file).

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on "auto-generating the `.tkenv` file"?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The `.tkenv` file is what the OMNeT++ TkEnv graphical user interface reads to determine which windows should be opened when the simulation starts. It is used to save window status and positions between sessions.